# Python regular expression findall

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all 2 word strings in python.
I created this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

string='a1 a2 a3 a5 a6'
search=re.findall('.. ..',string)
print len(search)
for nk in search:
        print nk
```

I am getting:
a1 a2
a3 a5
While I wanted:a1 a2,a2 a3,a3 a5,... etc
The findall should search for all possible patterns?
And why returns a1 a2,a3 a5?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `['a1 a2', 'a3 a5']`, because these are the only patterns which can be found: after applying the first one, the `'a1 a2'` part is gone and `' a3 a5 a6'` is left. The next possible pattern is `'a3 a5'`, and `' a6'` is left over and cannot be matched further.

`'a1 a3'`, `'a1 a5'` etc. cannot be found because this combinations don't occur. Remember, you search for two arbitrary characters, followed by a space character, followed by 2 arbitrary characters.

With

```
r=re.compile(r"(\S{2})(?:\s|$)")
pairs =r.findall("a1 a2 a3 a5 a6")
```

or

```
pairs = re.findall(r"(\S{2})(?:\s|$)", "a1 a2 a3 a5 a6")
```

you find all 2-character combination which are wither followed by a space or by the end of the string: `['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a5', 'a6']`. If you combine these, you will find all possible combinations:

```
for ifirst in range(len(pairs) - 1):
    for second in pairs[ifirst + 1:]:
        print " ".join((pairs[ifirst], second))
```

Comment: At first, I thought my monitor was dirty. Then I realized the h in "characters" had a caron.

Comment: If i want to find and a2-a3 is there any better way than running the search again on the original string without a1?

Comment: @NullUserException Thx for your regex; I added a `r` to make it a raw string and I added `()` for not finding the spaces after them. And thx for the caron hint :-)

Comment: @nikosdi Either that or you re-assemble the pair of pairs :-) again afterwards as shown in the example.

Comment: Or `items = 'a1 a2 a3 a5 a6'.split();['%s %s' % x for x in zip(items, items[1:])]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski But the `.split()` is great, I was thinking too complicated.